# How to set Crystal reports Connection info

Tags: c#, sql-server, crystal-reports

I use Crystal reports for reporting my application. The problem is that i didn't know how

to set the connection infos for Crystal reports. this is the code i tried:

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();

        TableLogOnInfos crtableLogoninfos = new TableLogOnInfos();
        TableLogOnInfo crtableLogoninfo = new TableLogOnInfo();
        ConnectionInfo crConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
        Tables CrTables;

        crConnectionInfo.ServerName = ".\\SQLEXPRESS";
        crConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "GestStock.mdf";
        crConnectionInfo.UserID = "";
        crConnectionInfo.Password = "";
        CrTables = cryRpt.Database.Tables;

        cryRpt.Load("C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrateur\\Mes documents\\GestionStock\\GestionStock\\CrystalReport1.rpt");

        foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table CrTable in CrTables)
        {
            crtableLogoninfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo;
            crtableLogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo;
            CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtableLogoninfo);
        }

        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt;
        crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
    }
```

But it doesn't work i got this error message:

```
Chemin d'accès au fichier de rapport non valide (Invalid report file path)
```

PS: this the connectionstring of my sql server database:

> "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\DOCUMENTS AND SETTINGS\ADMINISTRATEUR\MES DOCUMENTS\GESTIONSTOCK\GESTIONSTOCK\GestStock.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";

So how to set it in a correct way?

Comment: Can you convert the error message to English?

Comment: Invalid report file path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crystal Reports data source is based on a [**DataSet**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), so you have to first initialize an instance of the **DataSet** class, and fill it with information from your **DataSet**, then set its parameters based on your needs.

Nonetheless, your error message:

> *Chemin d'accès au fichier de rapport non valide* (Invalid report file path)

states that the file path to your report is invalid. So this has nothing to do with an unassigned or a misassigned connection string.

Here's an interesting answer which shows how to use a **DataSet** to fill in a Crystal report:

- [**How to fill in data from dataset to crystal report?**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4711564/162167)

Make sure your report gets loaded from the expected file path, and that it can access it (perhaps a concurrent access would be the cause of the problem)?

Once your report gets loaded as expected, then I guess you should try to use a data set to fill the report and set its data source with it as illustrated in the linked answer.

This way, your connection string gets assigned to the **SqlConnection** used to instantiate the **SqlCommand**, then your command is passed to [**SqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.selectcommand(v=vs.110).aspx) property. This way, you can use default credentials by specifying `Integrated Security=true` in your connection string and assigning it to the **SqlConnection** instance prior to open it.

Comment: Don't forget to include the initializations of the **SqlConnection**, **SqlCommand**, and everything that is disposable in a **using** block to manage resources adequately. (Glad I could help!)

Answer (score 1):

The basic code would be like this:-

```
        SqlConnection cnn ;
        string connectionString = null;
        string sql = null;

        connectionString = "data source=SERVERNAME;initial catalog=DATABASENAME;user  
                            id=USERNAME;password=PASSWORD;";
        cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        cnn.Open();
        sql = "SELECT columnName FROM tableName";
        SqlDataAdapter dscmd = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, cnn);
        DataSet1 ds = new DataSet1();
        dscmd.Fill(ds, "Product");
        MessageBox.Show (ds.Tables[1].Rows.Count.ToString());
        cnn.Close();

        CrystalReport1 objRpt = new CrystalReport1();
        objRpt.SetDataSource(ds.Tables[1]);
        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = objRpt;
        crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
```